# How to return results when sending a post request to a website and then choose one of them?

Tags: python, django, screen-scraping, data-science

I am trying to create a script which inputs text into www.citethisforme.com as a post request then chooses the first result.

I am sending a post request to www.citethisforme.com which submits the text "albert einstein" to the form which i found information for after inspecting the page. When i run the scipt is seems to work but when i copy and past the response I do not see the results in the response. How do i see the results? 
and then what would I code to click the first result and return the response ?

I have tried beautifulsoup and without beautiful soup but I am not getting the desired response or am i doing it wrong?

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

body = {'jrQry': 'albert einstein'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    con = requests.post("https://stackoverflow.com/", data=body)
    print (con.text)
```

if you enter albert einstein into www.citethisforme.com you should see what is expected with respects to the results.

Comment: you mean `print(con.text)` doesn't print anything?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a request to the home page you should make a request to the endpoint that they use to search. A good way to find this out is often to use the Developer's Console in your favourite browser, (e.g. for [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console) and see what requests are being made when you use the website.

Doing so when executing a search on the website you suggested shows a POST request being made to one their endpoints and the response it provides.

However, it is probably best to contact any website or check their documentation before doing something like this to make sure that it's ok. Querying what's supposed to be a frontend endpoint programtically could be considered an abuse of the service, especially if you're doing so at a higher-than-human rate.